# Sorbet: How do i write a generic factory method?

Tags: ruby, static-typing, sorbet

I have a factory method, which receives a class and returns an instance. In Java, i can express it this way:

**Java**

```java
class InstantiateMe { }

// Generic factory method
class Factory {

  public static <V> V createInstance(Class<V> type) {
    try {
      return type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}

// returns an instance of the class InstantiateMe
Factory.createInstance(InstantiateMe.class);
```

When trying to create a similar signature in sorbet, it ends up in an error. The error message of the static checker: `T.class_of needs a Class as its argument` for the signature of `Factory#createInstance`s.

**ruby/sorbet:**

```rb
# typed: true
class InstantiateMe; end

class Factory
  extend T::Sig

  sig do
    type_parameters(:V)
    params(klass: T.class_of(T.type_parameter(:V)))
    .returns(T.type_parameter(:V))
  end
  def self.createInstance(klass)
    klass.new
  end

end

Factory.createInstance(Factory)
```

Check online: [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20InstantiateMe%3B%20end%0A%0Aclass%20Factory%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20do%0A%20%20%20%20type_parameters(%3AV)%0A%20%20%20%20params(klass%3A%20T.class_of(T.type_parameter(%3AV)))%0A%20%20%20%20.returns(T.type_parameter(%3AV))%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20self.createInstance(klass)%0A%20%20%20%20klass.new%0A%20%20end%0A%0Aend%0A%0AFactory.createInstance(Factory))

Of course i see the point of accepting a class. However, the `T.type_parameter(:V)` is actually expressing a variable class. So it should be accepted as well. The same way as it is accepted in Java.

However, maybe i am just expressing it wrong. What's the correct way to write a generic factory signature in sorbet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Sorbet doesn't support it right now. It doesn't have the expression of `T.instance_of(:X)` and `T.class_of` doesn't work with Generic. We've brought this discussion up in sorbet slack a few times but it's not currently their priority to implement such feature.